# About kinetis K60 vector table address

Tags: arm, iar, cortex-m

how can I determine K60 vector table address. I know it is stored at `VTOR` register (0xE000ED08), but what value is it when reset, does it initialized different value for different K60 cpu, or initialize by some Peripheral device?

Comment: I'm curious where you got that 0xE000ED08 from?

Comment: The address for VTOR is standard for the Cortex-M core, so any devices that use that core have the VTOR register there. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/CIHGEFHJ.html

Answer (score 0):

The default vector table address for all Cortex-M devices is 0.

Comment: True, which means your vector table needs to be at the beginning of FLASH. However, once the CPU is started up you can set some registers to switch to a vector table somewhere else in memory (including SRAM).